# Select rows by "similar" ID

Tags: mysql, database, select, similarity, ranking

I have a database table `Image` with the two columns `ImagePath` and `UserID`.

My system requires users to input their User-ID in order to retrieve their own image.

However if a user input his User-ID wrongly (e.g. 123**3**56, which is not found in database), could there possibly be a way to select those "similar" ones in a ranked list from database?

An example sorted from most similar to least similar (Input User-ID `123356`):

```
123456 (his real ID), 123457, 124456, 123488, 113358,...so on
```

If yes, how should the SQL be?

Comment: Define'similar'

Comment: @Strawberry In my case, 'similar' means _does not differ much from the original_. 
If `123456` is the original one, those with minimal edit distance are most similar. `eg. 223456,123457, 123356 etc.`

Comment: So perhaps take a look at the Levenshtein distance algorithm

Comment: @Strawberry Thank  you very much, this is a great help!